# Count filter records in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I have a PHP/MYSQL based application in which there is a search area, when you search by dates then I show that a property/hotel is available between those dates. Also I have some other filters like area, facilities that Hotel has etc.

Now as of now everything working ok, but cutsomer now wants to show the number of records in bracket for each filter.

I tried it by adding multiple queries for each filter based on dynamic search user did, but that making my page performance slow. Because if I have 5 filters then I will run 5 queries.

I have seen such thing in magento, it counts the number of result that filter have as shown in picture below:

[image]

What will be the best method of doing this, I just need some logic and procedure which can be followed to resolve this.

Posting whole table structure is difficult, but I am positing shorter for of it, so you guys may have some idea and suggest some solution:

Tables are:

```
Properties - id, name
Factsheet_label - label_id, Name
Factsheet - id, label_id, prop_id, value (Yes, No)
```

I am showing all the filters from factsheet_label table and then I need to count the result of properties I have.

Comment: use mysql_num_rows and give particular category_id to get the count

Comment: It depends upon how you've got your query set up. If you are using GROUP BY then you can use the COUNT() to get the number of entries for that group.

Comment: @RizwanSultan No, I have shown that as an example, so if you click on Price range 0-999 then it will show Red (2) which means we need to calculate the number of records for each filter dynamically. And for that one option I think is running queries for each filter but that is making my page slow.

Comment: We'll need to see the query/queries you are using to assist here, I think. Bear in mind, running more queries _may_ be faster than running a single query to do what you want - if you have tried something, please add that into your question, and details of the execution times, so we can see what you want to improve on.

Comment: show the table structure it would be useful to give you correct answer

Comment: I am afraid that is a very long query and it involves multiple tables, views. Posting the whole thing is difficult here.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: I have posted shorter form of tables so you guys can have some idea of what I am trying to do. Please check!

Comment: Yes it is duplicate but in that question no one was replying, so asked a new question.

Comment: [`Someone did reply()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9374420/)

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions. You have enough rep to add a bounty. It seems you didn't respond to either of the people who helped you on the other question, which is expected of 1-rep users, but not high rep users. Since this question was also missing essential technical detail, with regret I am downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

A statement like this

`SELECT categoryId,CategoryName,COUNT(*) FROM Products GROUP BY CategoryId,CategoryName`

will group the results by category and return a count of each, like so

```
CategoryId  CategoryName  Count
1           Living Room   4
2           Bedroom       2
```

**EDIT**

This should do it, if I've understood your tables correctly.

```
SELECT F.id,F.label_id,F.prop_id,F.value,L.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Properties WHERE id = F.prop_id)
FROM FactSheet F
LEFT JOIN FactSheet_label L on L.label_id = F.Label_id
```

All data is pulled from Factsheet. the relevant label is pulled from factsheet_label. The count is then retreived for each row via a subquery

Here's another way to do it, which may or may not be a little more efficient.

```
SELECT F.id,F.label_id,F.prop_id,F.value,L.Name,P.count
FROM FactSheet F
LEFT JOIN FactSheet_label L on L.label_id = F.Label_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,COUNT(*) count FROM Properties GROUP BY id) P ON P.id = F.prop_id
```

Comment: Which means for counting records, I need to run a separate query, right?

Comment: It should be possible to do in one single Stored Procedure, but without more information about your database schema I can't really help. How are the tables layed out?

Comment: I have added some details about tables in question, please check.

Comment: can you add the select statement you currently use to get the data? I'm still not sure from the info you've given where the data is.

Answer (score 0):

Every "SELECT *" can be a "SELECT *, COUNT(*) ...." then you can see the nr of the results.
To help you more I need to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tab1
        ) AS count1,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tab2
        ) AS count2
FROM    dual
```